# Playwright: what is the drawbacks/advantages of enabling reuseExistingServer for CI?

Tags: continuous-integration, github-actions, playwright

Docs: https://playwright.dev/docs/api/class-testconfig#test-config-web-server

I can't seem to understand this well, what are the drawbacks/advantages of enabling reuseExistingServer for CI only vs disabling it on CI?

I am currently getting this error on my github actions CI pipeline when tests are running for my monorepo setup multiple packages:

> Error: http://localhost:3000 is already used, make sure that nothing is running on the port/url or set reuseExistingServer:true in config.webServer.

This is my playwright config:

```
import type { PlaywrightTestConfig } from '@playwright/test';
import { devices } from '@playwright/test';

declare const process: {
  env: {
    CI?: string;
  };
};

/**
 * See https://playwright.dev/docs/test-configuration.
 */
const config: PlaywrightTestConfig = {
  testDir: './tests',

  /* Maximum time one test can run for. */
  timeout: 30 * 1000,
  expect: {
    /**
     * Maximum time expect() should wait for the condition to be met.
     * For example in `await expect(locator).toHaveText();`
     */
    timeout: 5000,
  },

  /* Run tests in files in parallel */
  fullyParallel: true,

  /* Fail the build on CI if you accidentally left test.only in the source code. */
  forbidOnly: !!process.env.CI,

  /* Retry on CI only */
  retries: process.env.CI ? 2 : 0,

  /* Opt out of parallel tests on CI. */
  workers: process.env.CI ? 1 : undefined,

  /* Reporter to use. See https://playwright.dev/docs/test-reporters */
  reporter: process.env.CI ? 'dot' : 'list',

  /* Shared settings for all the projects below. See https://playwright.dev/docs/api/class-testoptions. */
  use: {
    /* Maximum time each action such as `click()` can take. Defaults to 0 (no limit). */
    actionTimeout: 0,
    /* Base URL to use in actions like `await page.goto('/')`. */
    // baseURL: 'http://localhost:3000',

    /* Collect trace when retrying the failed test. See https://playwright.dev/docs/trace-viewer */
    trace: 'on-first-retry',
  },

  /* Configure projects for major browsers */
  projects: [
    {
      name: 'chromium',
      use: {
        ...devices['Desktop Chrome'],
      },
    },

    {
      name: 'firefox',
      use: {
        ...devices['Desktop Firefox'],
      },
    },

    {
      name: 'webkit',
      use: {
        ...devices['Desktop Safari'],
      },
    },
  ],

  /* Run your local dev server before starting the tests */
  webServer: {
    command: 'pnpm dev',
    port: 3000,
  },
};

export default config;
```

but if I change the `webServer` configs to include `reuseExistingServer` on CI:

```
  webServer: {
    command: 'pnpm dev',
    port: 3000,
    reuseExistingServer: !!process.env.CI,
  },
```

My tests are now running well. I will appreciate some insights what is happening here, because the docs recommend to disable `reuseExistingServer` on CI, yet for my case it actually seems to be working well for me when I enable `reuseExistingServer` this on CI.

Answer (score 0):

from [Playwright Docs](https://playwright.dev/docs/test-webserver):

> This is ideal for when writing your tests during development and when
> you don't have a staging or production url to test against.

My conclusion is, by setting `reuseExistingServer: !process.env.CI` in local development `reuseExistingServer` will be `true` which means Playwright expects you to have your dev server running and therefore reuse it so that you do not have to stop your dev instance everytime you want to run tests.

Then, in CI, `reuseExistingServer` will be false because, from the docs mentioned above:

> when you don't have a staging or production url to test against.

Playwright assumes you do not have a staging or prod URL ready to test against and therefore will start whatever server command, in your example `command: 'pnpm dev'` and run the tests against that server instance.

The example does not make sense if indeed you have a staging/prod/preview URL. In that case `reuseExistingServer` should be set to `true`.